# Read a JSON file and append JSON objects to a JSON Array

Tags: python, json, file-handling

I have a JSON file name.json with below contents,

```
{
    "Name": [{
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Stark"
    }]
}
```

Using python how to add the members of Stark family to the JSON file using following list
`firstNameList=['Sansa','Arya','Brandon']`

Expected Output

```
{
    "Name": [{
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Stark"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Sansa",
            "lastName": "Stark"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Arya",
            "lastName": "Stark"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Brandon",
            "lastName": "Stark"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried:

```
firstNameList=['arya', 'sansa','brandon']
import json
with open('/name.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for item in firstNameList:
        Name['firstname']=item  
    f.seek(0)        #reset file position to the beginning.
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: My approach didn't work but tried the below one:
```
firstNameList=['arya', 'sansa','brandon']
import json
with open('/test1.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for item in firstNameList:
        Name['firstname']=item  
    f.seek(0)        #reset file position to the beginning.
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: Don't post your code attempt in the comments, edit the question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
import json
test = '''{
    "Name": [{
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Stark"
    }]
}'''
data  = json.loads(test)
firstNameList = ['Sansa','Arya','Brandon']
for member in firstNameList:
    test_dict = {'firstName': member, 'lastName': 'Stark'}
    data['Name'].append(test_dict)
dump = json.dumps(data)
print(dump)
```

This uses the json library to parse into a dictionary, make the changes and dump back to json.

Output

```
{"Name": [{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Stark"}, {"firstName": "Sansa", "lastName": "Stark"}, {"firstName": "Arya", "lastName": "Stark"}, {"firstName": "Brandon", "lastName": "Stark"}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should do the trick:

```
import json 


with open('name.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    for name in firstNameList:
        data["Name"].append({"firstName": name, "lastName": "Stark"})
```

Comment: @Giorgos Myrianthous , I tried what is suggested, but it is not giving desired result. Please check.
I wanted to add the results in the comments only but couldn't do that, thus editing your answer, Thanks!!

Comment: got that we have use f.seek(0)

Answer (score 0):

```
dicts = {
    "Name": [{
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Stark"
        }
    ]
}

firstNameList = ['Sansa','Arya','Brandon']


for j in firstNameList:
    dicts["Name"].append({'firstName': j, 'lastName': 'Stark'})

print(dicts)
```

And you will get

```
{'Name': [{'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'Stark'}, {'firstName': 'Sansa', 'lastName': 'Stark'}, {'firstName': 'Arya', 'lastName': 'Stark'}, {'firstName': 'Brandon', 'lastName': 'Stark'}]}
```